# How to upload files via dropbox or skydrive without browser authentication

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, xna, dropbox

I have a big 3d game that lets players build and create interesting and huge worlds and save them to disk on windows phone 7.

The game uses XNA and does many things that are not supported in silverlight or SLXNA hybrid apps.

I want to let the players backup there save files to their skydrive (preferable) or dropbox but after more than a week trying to get some kind of implimentation working I have came up with nothing...

It seems that every single sample for eather is built in (and requires) siverlight and a web browser to work.

**Does anyone know of a way to overcome these limitations?** I have almost 100,000 people with my game and the most requested feature is cloudbackups...

Thanks!

Comment: is it requrements to use skydrive or dropbox? Maybe it'll be better using special cloud-based services for this puprose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mmmm i think it wouldnt be difficult.

I worked in a web app project where the server do all the authentication stuff. Of course you always need to open a browser windows to let the user enters its credentials.

When the user enters its credentials, skydrive, dropbox or whatever gives you a TOKEN a then you use that TOKEN to do operations in the name of the user (eg: upload file to dropbox) doing REST (webrequest) and JSON

do you have any experience with REST, JSON, etc?

I think, you will need to use Oauth for desktop (here's google explanation https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2?hl=es)

Did you see un / official  sdk? 
skydrive: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/hh826521
dropbox:

- https://www.dropbox.com/developers
- http://sharpbox.codeplex.com/

Greetings from Argentina
HERNAN

PS: sorry about my awful english :)